# C Macro to remove duplicates in list of arguments

Tags: c, macros, p99

I wonder if it is possible to build a gnu C macro which expands to a list of tokens (integer numbers) which are the arguments of the macro without duplicates. The number of arguments could be assumed fixed (for the moment). I.e. I want something like:

```
#define MAC(a,b,c) ???
```

which expands e.g.

```
MAC(1,2,1)
```

to `1,2`.
The arguments are not sorted and the result does not have to be.

---

Based on the proposal below I built an example which does essentially what I want using the p99 includes:

```
#include <p99/p99_if.h>
#include <p99/p99_paste.h>

#define MAC2(a,b) double P99_PASTE2(myvar_, a) P99_IF_EQ(a,b)()(; double P99_PASTE2(myvar_, b))
#define MAC3(a,b,c) double P99_PASTE2(myvar_, a) P99_IF_EQ(a,b)()(; double P99_PASTE2(myvar_, b)) P99_IF_EQ(a,c)()(P99_IF_EQ(b,c)()(; double P99_PASTE2(myvar_, c)) )

MAC2(1,2);
MAC2(3,3);

MAC3(1,2,3);
MAC3(10,10,1);
```

Comment: Pretty hard to imagine why you would prefer to write `MAC(1,2,1)` rather than simply writing `1,2`.

Comment: Admittedly the application is not obvious. I want to define a set of variables which depends on the indices (which are the arguments of MAC). But the three indices over-determine the variables. Only part of the information is needed. Of course I could reduce the list of indices by hand, but this would lead to inconsistent code if I make mistakes.

Comment: why not write a function looking like `int * unique_list(int*, int )` or `void remove_duplicates(int *, int)`

Comment: @UmNyobe: the expression needs to be expanded before compilation as it should determine variable names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your arguments are always small decimal numbers as in your example, you *could* get away with what I provide in [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr). It has macros like `P99_IF_EQ` that you could use as

```
#define MAC(A,B) unsigned P99_PASTE2(myvar_, A) P99_IF_EQ(A,B)()(; unsigned P99(unsigned P99_PASTE2(myvar_, B))

MAC(1,2); // -> myvar_1 and myvar_2
MAC(3,3); // -> myvar_3
```

to only expand the declaration for `B` if it is not equal to `A`. Obviously for three different arguments this already becomes a bit tedious, but would be doable.

Comment: I decided o give it a try. It has different features I could use. I downloaded and successfully compiled test examples with gcc. Strangely with `icc -I /usr/local/include/p99 -Wall -c -o test-p99-double -std=c99 test-p99-double.c` (version 13.0.1) I get: `/usr/local/include/p99/p99_block.h(473): error: expected a ";"
  void p00_longjmp(p00_jmp_buf0 * p00_buf, int p00_val) {
  ^

test-p99-double.c(56): warning #12: parsing restarts here after previous syntax error
    P99_IS_GT(1, 1);` and many more. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This lacks a closing round bracket. I modified your answer as to account for three indices, see my modified question. Unfortunately I still don't get it to work with icc. The preprocessor produces code which does not compile.

Comment: I found that it compiles with `icc` when omitting `#line` directives: `icc -I /usr/local/include -std=c99 -P -o test test.c`

Comment: @highsciguy, AFAIR icc has problems with C99. And since it is not free, I don't always have a version available for testing. Could you please send me a detailed report and/or patch through other chanels? Thanks.